# How to get date for specific weekday and then format

Tags: javascript, date

So I've been able to find the specific weekday date (the next upcoming Wednesday) I need with the following code:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + (3 - 1 - date.getDay() + 7) % 7 + 1);
```

However I'm now trying to format it in a way that suits me but I can't work out how. I tried this:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + (3 - 1 - date.getDay() + 7) % 7 + 1);
var day = date.getDay();
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var month = monthNames[date.getMonth()];
var year = date.getFullYear();
console.log(day, month, year);
```

But I get today's date again, I guess because I'm calling getDay/getMonth/getYear again. I just want to format the date returned to the 'date' variable but I can't work out how. I also don't understand how that date is calculated as I took it from another question which had no explanation.

I want it displayed as '10 February 2016' I don't want to use a library either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `date.getDate()` instead of `date.getDay()`

so your code should be

```
var day = date.getDate();
```

The getDay() method returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time, where 0 represents Sunday.

[Date.prototype.getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking getDate returned the whole date.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression to get the next Wednesday seems a bit convoluted, consider:

```
var x = 3 - date.getDay();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + (x > 0? x : 7 + x));
```

or if you really want to do it in one line:

```
date.setDate(date.getDate() + ((3 - date.getDay() + 7)%7 || 7));
```

If *date* is a Wednesday, this will return the next Wednesday (i.e. *date* plus 7 days).